# How to install python packages like pip, numpy on Amazon EC2 - ubuntu

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

Need to install python packages like pip, numpy, cv2 on an Amazon EC2 instance of Ubuntu.  I tried using sudo apt-get install python-pip but got below given error:

ubuntu@ip-172-31-35-131:~$ sudo apt-get install python-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-pip

Answer (score 9):

Try first `sudo apt-get update` then

`sudo apt-get install python-pip`

Comment: Worked for me with `sudo apt-get install python3-pip`

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the instructions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-install-linux.html)?

You can install pip from PyPa directly:

```
curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
python get-pip.py --user
```

Your system may have a concurrent python3.x under the name `python3`, then you can install pip for it with `python3 get-pip.py --user` as well. (Or contrarily, python2.x under the name `python2`.)